# Logout from Facebook within app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

Is it possible to implement a Facebook logout function within an application? I am using latest Facebook SDK (3.1)

Answer (score 2):

You can logout within app because it works on single sign on.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for logout

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:nil forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"SignInWithFaceBokk"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil  forKey:@"selectedUSAState"];

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you already added facebook framework to your project
and

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

in the **view-controller** you're using..
and added

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

to your **app delegate** 
if you did all then
make a **button** with an action and call:

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
```

Only two line works for me ...